# O que é o RunLoop?

Tags: ios, runloop, objective-c, thread

Gostaria de saber o que é o RunLoop em iOS e de que maneira ele e a thread correspondente interagem.

Também seria interessante entender como é que estes dois conceitos interagem com a autorelease pool.

Answer (score 9):

Toda *thread* possui um *run loop* (instância de `NSRunLoop`), que é responsável por tratar eventos, como um toque na tela ou a execução de um método agendado com `NSTimer`.

Segundo o [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html):

> Um *run loop* é um loop de processamento de eventos que você usa para agendar tarefas e coordenar a recepção de eventos de entrada. O propósito de um *run loop* é manter sua *thread* ocupada quando há tarefas a realizar e colocar a *thread* para dormir quando não há.

Em geral você é quem deve executar o *run loop* associado à *thread*, se assim desejar. No caso da *thread* principal, responsável por tratar eventos relacionados à interface com o usuário, o sistema se encarrega de executar o *run loop*.

A cada iteração do *run loop*, é criado um *autorelease pool* no início, que é drenado no final da iteração, após o tratamento de um evento. Isso garante que os objetos criados durante o tratamento de um evento não serão desalocados até o final do tratamento, quando acaba a iteração do *run loop*.

Espero ter passado uma ideia geral sobre *run loops*, suficiente para a maioria dos usos práticos. Se quiser se aprofundar, recomendo ler o [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html), que trata de portas, modos e outros conceitos associados a *run loops*.